# Remote connect from work into my home network which has CentOS 7.3 running under VirtualBox under Windows 8 Host OS

Tags: networking, router, ssh, virtualbox

I have been trying to set this up unsuccessfully for many hours now.  I was able to configure my VirtualBox with 2 adapters (1. NAT,  2. Host-Only),   and I confirmed that I am able to ssh from the host OS into the vbox guest OS without problem.

I then configured VirtualBox's NAT adapter to port forward 4022 to 22.  After this, I went into my Router's configuration (TP-LINK Archer C7 Router), and configured Port Forwarding,  by setting,  Server Port: 4022,  Internal Port: 4022, IP Address: <IP address of centos_in_vbox>.

After all of this has been set up I attempt to run a test from a remote Linux server on the Internet by attempt to do a simple test of doing a:

```
> telnet my_external_ip_number 4022
Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
telnet: connect to address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: No route to host
```

It appears that the setup is not working.  Any ideas what I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe your Host OS Firewall is blocking port 4022? Have you tried using a different machine within your network and see if you can go directly to your Host OS IP:4022 and see if that works?

Comment: This sounds like your problem is more basic than anything having to do with ssh, port forwarding or virtual machines.  It sounds like the external computer (work?) simply cannot see your home network.  Are you sure your external IP is correct?  Have you ever connected to your home network from outside before?  What happens if you try to ping or tracert?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: You wouldn't configure your router to port forward to the IP of the guest OS. You would port forward to the Windows IP because it is doing the NATting. However, this type of multiple NATting is frankly silly, get rid of the NAT interface and add a bridged network. Then port forward on your router directly to your guest OS. The added layer of complexity using a NAT interface has no benefits.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions, they helped me isolate the problem.  The problem indeed was with the Windows Firewall but it was not an obvious issue:  I had installed VirtualBox last year and when it was launched for the first time, I must have specified some firewall settings which the Windows Firewall remembered.  What I ended up having to do was to disable any Windows Firewalls related to VirtualBox itself,  and to define a custom Incoming rule where I configured the specific port 4022 to be allowed to come in.  This made it possible for the external host to initiate an ssh session.